# Check if external chrome extension exists

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i'd like to check if the tuxler extension exists in browsers of visitors to my site. This is the extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/free-residential-vpn-tuxl/jpgljfpmoofbmlieejglhonfofmahini/related

The first thing I tried was this simple line:

```
var myPort=chrome.extension.connect('yourextensionid_qwerqweroijwefoijwef', some_object_to_send_on_connect);
```

Then I learned that google patched that. The next thing I tried was this:

```
const checkExtension = (id, src, callback) => {
    let e = new Image()
    e.src = 'chrome-extension://'+ id +'/'+ src
    e.onload = () => callback(1), e.onerror = () => callback(0)
}

// "src" must be included to "web_accessible_resources" in manifest.json
checkExtension('gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom', 'icons/icon24.png', (ok) => {
    console.log('AdBlock: %s', ok ? 'installed' : 'not installed')
})
checkExtension('bhlhnicpbhignbdhedgjhgdocnmhomnp', 'images/checkmark-icon.png', (ok) => {
    console.log('ColorZilla: %s', ok ? 'installed' : 'not installed')
})
```

And I was quite happy that worked! The only issue is, the extension has to have whatever resource we call in the 'web_accessible_resources', but this tuxler VPN doesn't have that. I'm not really sure how to check if it's in the user's browser. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just as a mention, you already noticed with "google patched that", that any method may suddenly stop working tomorrow. Moreover, the more common such an exploit is, the more likely google is to fix it. I'd laugh, if someone posted a method, and then a chrome- or extension-dev comes, and comments "thanks, gonna fix that, brb".

Comment: @ASDFGerte lmao, you're right. Alright then.